# Python/OpenCV - how to load all images from folder in alphabetical order

Tags: python, opencv

how to load all images from given folder in alphabetical order?

Code like this:

```
images = []
for img in glob.glob("images/*.jpg"):
    n= cv2.imread(img)
    images.append(n)
    print (img)
```

...return:

```
...
images/IMG_9409.jpg
images/IMG_9425.jpg
images/IMG_9419.jpg
images/IMG_9376.jpg
images/IMG_9368.jpg
images/IMG_9417.jpg
...
```

Is there a way to get all images but in correct order?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Luckily, python lists have a built-in sort function that can sort strings using ASCII values. It is as simple as putting this before your loop:

```
filenames = [img for img in glob.glob("images/*.jpg")]

filenames.sort() # ADD THIS LINE

images = []
for img in filenames:
    n= cv2.imread(img)
    images.append(n)
    print (img)
```

**EDIT:** Knowing a little more about python now than I did when I first answered this, you could actually simplify this a lot:

```
filenames = glob.glob("images/*.jpg")
filenames.sort()
images = [cv2.imread(img) for img in filenames]

for img in images:
    print img
```

Should be much faster too. Yay list comprehensions!

Comment: That's what I was looking for! :) Maybe it's obvious solution but I'm new in python and I couldn't find it myself.

Comment: Just wanted to add that you shouldn't add the square brackets around 'glob.glob("images/*.jpg")'. Adding them creates a list of size 1.

Comment: @BobsonDugnutt fixed

Comment: This is great! Not OP but thanks a lot. As for the last part of your code, what if I don't want to show them in other applications but rather generate them as output in my Jupyter Notebook? I used your code and hundreds of pictures popped up using Window's default app. Thanks again

Comment: this did not work for me as when I plotted I cleary was not getting them in order of `1.png`, `2.png`, ...`150.png`  ie. `100.png` comes before `2.png`.

Comment: @flexitarian33 yes this is a limitation of this method, one workaround is to include the trailing 0’s in your filenames, for example 001.png, etc. Then the sort function will work correctly.

Answer (score 0):

As people mentioned, filenames.sort() order is not natural order for solve this problem use:

> natsorted

```
file=natsorted (filenames) # ADD THIS LINE
images = []
for img in file:
    n= cv2.imread(img)
    images.append(n)
```