# error while while creating image dataset using cv2 in python

Tags: python, opencv

I'm getting below error while creating image dataset using cv2:

```
main_dir = '/content/drive/My Drive/DL-Datasets/cat-and-dog/training_set/training_set/'
categories = ['cats', 'dogs']
X = []
y = []

def create_training_data():
    for categ in categories:
        path = os.path.join(main_dir,categ)
        categ_no = categories.index(categ)
        for img in os.listdir(path):
            image_array = cv2.imread(os.path.join(path,img))
            new_array = cv2.resize(image_array, dsize=(80,80))
            X.append(new_array)
            y.append(categ_no)

create_training_data()
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last)
        <ipython-input-3-850769b91ea0> in <module>()
             12       X.append(new_array)
             13       y.append(categ_no)
        ---> 14 create_training_data()
        
        <ipython-input-3-850769b91ea0> in create_training_data()
              9     for img in os.listdir(path):
             10       image_array = cv2.imread(os.path.join(path,img))
        ---> 11       new_array = cv2.resize(image_array, dsize=(80,80))
             12       X.append(new_array)
             13       y.append(categ_no)
        
        error: OpenCV(4.1.2) /io/opencv/modules/imgproc/src/resize.cpp:3720: error: (-215:Assertion failed) !ssize.empty() in function 'resize'
```

Although images are there in directory for resizing, still getting the error.

Answer (score 0):

Fault lies in your 10th line of code.Some how your image_array is not a cv2 image.Try the solution below instead of your last for loop.
[Python/OpenCV - how to load all images from folder in alphabetical order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38675389/python-opencv-how-to-load-all-images-from-folder-in-alphabetical-order)

Comment: Please check EDITED code in my question, when I run it, it works, although same loop. any idea?

Comment: yes you were right, my 2nd loop was wrong in my initial code. But now after correcting and rerunning code, kernel is taking too long. Any idea how long will it take to loop through 20 thousand images?

Comment: depends on dimensions of images and your gpu. Also whether you are using your gpu or not.

Comment: 250*250... I am using google colab and I chose gpu..but I am skeptical whether gpu is being utilized as message pops up gpu is idle, you may switch to standard runtime

Comment: I highly recommend enabling the gpu. On most online kernels you have to explicitly enable it.When working with images it reduces load on cpu and time needed exponentially.Although 250*250 is not a big size.